# Embedding C# Language in an Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to embed c# syntax highlighting in a VSC Extension.

My `tmLanguange.json` is as follows

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "CS Asm",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include":"#csasm"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "csasm" :{
            "patterns": [{
                "name" : "meta.embedded.block.bmasm",
                "begin": "@{",
                "end": "}",
                "patterns" : [{
                    "include" : "source.csharp"
                }]
            }]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.csasm"
}
```

However this doesn't produce any highlighting within VSC. If I change `source.csharp` to something else it does work.

Normal .cs files are highlighted properly, so I assume there is a 'csharp' extension loaded to provide the syntax rules.

Is there something special about C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Microsoft defines `source.cs` not `source.csharp`,

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/csharp/package.json#L33

Comment: Genius. Yet its csharp in the drop downs.

Comment: @BJury `language` and `scopeName` can be defined with different values (for C# and many other languages), and your syntax needs to apply `scopeName`.

Comment: Aye, thanks. Just why couldn't they be consistent...?

Comment: @BJury we can only guess that the value `source.cs` of `scopeName` might refer to the file extension `.cs` while the full name `csharp` is more suitable for `language`.